# Выделение checkbox'а по ссылке

Tags: javascript

Добрый вечер, помогите решить такую проблему, пишу сайт для провайдера, и уже 2 часа бьюсь с проблемой выделения чекбокса по ссылке, ниже привожу код:

```
    foreach ($this->data['tariffs'] as $tarrifs){

    $this->tar .= '<form class="'.$tarrifs["id"].'" ><div class="tarif-econom">
        <div class="tarif-name">'.$tarrifs["title"].'</div>
        <div class="tarif-about">
            '.$tarrifs["discr"].'
        </div>

        <div class="download-time">
        <div class="download-time-clock-sector"><img src="'.base_url().'img/clock1.png"></div>
        <div class="download-time-text">'.$tarrifs["img"].' мин загружается фильм обычного качества (1,4 ГБ)</div>
        </div>

        <table class="table-with-tarrifs"><tr>
                <td>Скорость до</td>
                <td class="value">
                    6 Мбит/сек
                </td>
            </tr><tr>
                <td>Ежемесячный платеж</td>
                <td class="value">
                    60 грн
                </td>
            </tr></table>
        <a  class="button-full" onclick="checked('.$tarrifs["id"].')" >Подключить</a><div class="chk"><input  type="checkbox" name="tarif[]" id="tarif" value="'.$tarrifs["title"].'" style="width: 20px; height: 20px;"   ></div>
    </div></form>';
}
```

Это заявка на подключение тарифа, и это часть кода которая соответствует выбору тарифа, внизу есть чекбокс, но для слепых есть еще и кнопка "Подключить", так вот при нажатии на эту кнопку отмечаются чекбоксы, которые находятся в форме с классом `<form class="'.$tarrifs["id"].'" >`, то есть, выводятся 4 тарифа и в имя класса попадает разные id тарифа, для последующей обработки JS. Так вот проблема заключается в том, что чекбоксы нормально отмечаются только после первого тарифа, например на страницу попадает 4-ре тарифа, при нажатии на кнопку срабатывает onclick, отмечаются нормально 2,3,4 а вот 1-й никак не хочет, и  не могу понять в чем дело, ниже код JS:

```
function checked(forms) {
var selectedElements = $("."+forms+" input:checkbox").attr('checked', 'checked');
//var selectedElements = $("form[id = "+ forms + "] input:checkbox").attr('checked', 'checked');

//alert(forms);
```

}

Comment: Попробуйте так:

    $("."+forms+" input:checkbox").prop('checked', true);

Comment: Такая-же история, первый не выделяется!

Comment: Пробуйте через цикл пробежаться по всем чекбоксам:

    $('.' + forms + ' :checkbox').map(function(el, i){
        return $(el).prop('checked', true);
    });
    // или 
    $('.' + forms + ' :checkbox').each(function(){
        $(this).prop('checked', true);
    });

Comment: Начнем с того, что у вас на странице получаются несколько элементов с одинаковым id="tarif".

Comment: Да все верно, но выбираю я только те которые находятся внутри формы с классом равным ид тарифа <form class="'.$tarrifs["id"].'" >

Comment: Я к тому говорю, что на странице не должно быть одинаковых id.